# Can you change the color of the turtle pen in a while loop using a list?

Tags: python, list, while-loop, turtle-graphics

I want to know if you could change the color of the python turtle pen when a while loop iterates and continue to change everytime the while loop iterates. So far I have this but want to make it change color too.

```
from turtle import *

w = 10
# Number of steps to take
x = 40
# Number of sides to make
y = 2
# Size of turtle pen
z = x
# Same variable as x but not manipulated
speed ('fastest')
# Speed of pen 

    for i in range(10):
        while x > 0:
            pensize (y)
            forward (w)
            left (360/z)
            x = x-1
            y = y+1
        while x < z:
            pensize (y)
            forward (w)
            right (360/z)
            x = x+1
            y = y-1
        print (i)
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: I **highly** recommend not using single-character variable names.  Use descriptive names and ditch the comments.

Comment: I _figured_ but I use them to keep track of things and use variables quickly.

Comment: Totally not worth it.  All code has to be maintained.  Even code that the author considers "one-off".

Comment: What's the problem? Isn't your lst long enough to have an antry for every stroke? Don't know how to get a value out of the list? Don't know how to set the color at all?

Comment: The key to @TrippKinetics's comment is using _descriptive_ variable names. If `x` were an x position, for example, then that would be a fine name. This is a beginner question that could have been easily answered by looking at the documentation, so here's something more significant to learn: _programming is not hard because of anything except understanding-what's-going-on. Descriptive variable names are part of that. There is *literally no excuse* not to use them._

Comment: I understand what all of you are trying to say, but I'm trying to get help for a use and function of the program. So if anyone else has a comment over the fact this is too simple and lacks descriptive variables, please refrain from posting it. And anyone that wants to help, ignore the fact that I used single letter variables and give me some advice on the coding. Please and thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There is a `pencolor` function, so, yes, you can change the color.

If your problem is not turtle, but taking the values elegantly out of a too short list, I suggest `itertools`, and the `next()` method.

```
from itertools import cycle
color_sequence = cycle([4,5,6])
for i in range(10): print color_sequence.next()
```

And if you don't want to to have an extra command for every stroke, you just replace the call to `forward()` by a call to your own `list_colored_forward()`.